# VBA how do i have the same code on a command button but with changed variables

Tags: vba

completely new to VBA (and coding really) and have started today so i can imagine this problem has a relatively simple fix.

I want to create a revision logger for multiple subjects and the code just for 1 subject is working great. Here is what i have got. (i cannot place pictures so here is the link.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjGSh.png

here is the code for the command button (notr stands for number of times revised)

```
Private Sub revision_Click()

Dim check As String

If revision.Caption = "StartRevision" Then
revision.Caption = "EndRevision"
Else
revision.Caption = "StartRevision"
End If

Dim column As Integer
Dim notr As Integer

notr = Cells(*2*, 5).Value
column = notr + 6


If revision.Caption = "StartRevision" Then
Cells(*3*, column).Value = Now
Cells(*3*, column).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
Cells(*4*, column).Value = Abs((Cells(2, column)) - (Cells(3, column)))
Cells(*4*, column).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
Else
Cells(*2*, column).Value = Now
Cells(*2*, column).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
End If


If revision.Caption = "StartRevision" Then
notr = notr + 1
Cells(*2*, 5).Value = notr
End If


End Sub
```

now though i wish to copy and paste that command button for the other subjects. Now i can do this easily by changing the numbers i have labelled with *'s every time for each button but i was wondering if there is a way of doing this but making those * numbers variables and just have that code once and then for each subject just have to change those variables instead of having to copy and paste the whole code many times.

i understand that iam not being very clear so sorry :( but any help would be much appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: no iam able to just repeat the code for each button it works fine. Iam simply asking is there a way to do it so that i dont have to repeat the code and can just make those *'s variables and then for each button just have a list of what numbers for a certain subject should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of putting all your code on the button click event have a separate sub which takes a parameter(s) for the elements you want to change. So instead of a first line as this:

```
Private Sub revision_Click()
```

Use this:

```
Private Sub revision(MyVar As Long)
```

Then replace the parts of your code you want to change by using MyVar, this will take a bit of reworking to get the cell numbers you want from the one number. Then for each button use some code like so:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
  revision 1
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click()
  revision 2
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much, i didnt think anyone would understand what i was talking about with my post as it is so unclear XD. this is exactly what i wanted.